# Is serializing objects nested inside array differently using FormData?

Tags: javascript, json, webforms

I'm trying to serializing a web form using FormData(). My backend is Python's Cherrypy server.

The expected JSON is something like this:

```
{
   "price":1,
   "quantity_left":100,
   "packaging_weight":2,
   "variant_names":[
      {
         "name_line":"苹果",
         "is_primary_identifying_flag":"on"
      },
      {
         "name_line":"apple"
      }
   ]
}
```

However, after serialzing `var form_data = new FormData(this.inner_form);` and adding the array manually by `FormData.append`, the JSON becomes:

```
    {
       "price":1,
       "quantity_left":100,
       "packaging_weight":2,
       "variant_names":[object, Object]
    }
```

Isn't FormData able to process nested ojbects like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The values of a FormData [must be a string or Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append):

> The field's value. This can be a `USVString` or `Blob` (including subclasses such as File). If none of these are specified the value is converted to a string.

Rather than using FormData, consider just stringifying the whole object and then send that as the payload. Or, stringify inner values which are objects (and decode them on the server).